# Get first element of Pandas Series of string

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I think I have a relatively simply question but am not able to locate an appropriate answer to solve the coding problem.

I have a pandas column of string:
`df1['tweet'].head(1)
0                                        besides food,
Name: tweet`

I need to extract the text and push it into a Python str object, of this format:

`test_messages = ["line1",
    "line2",
    "etc"]`

The goal is to classify a test set of tweets and therefore believe the input to: `X_test = tfidf.transform(test_messages)` is a str object.

Comment: Are you just trying to do `list(df1["tweet"])`... ?

Comment: @AndyHayden looks like you saved the day again... thanks.

Comment: Related: [Pandas - Get first row value of a given column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254016/pandas-get-first-row-value-of-a-given-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list` convert a Series (column) into a python list:

```
list(df1["tweet"])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the Series `head()`, then access the first value:

   `df1['tweet'].head(1).item()`
2. or: Use the Series `tolist()` method, then slice the 0'th element:

   `df.height.tolist()
   [94, 170]
   df.height.tolist()[0]
   94`

(Note that Python indexing is 0-based, but `head()` is 1-based)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 : `df1['tweet'][0] or df1.loc[0, 'tweet']` 
Option 2 : `df1['tweet'].to_list()[0]`