# Get first row value of a given column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, head

This seems like a ridiculously easy question... but I'm not seeing the easy answer I was expecting.

So, how do I get the value at an nth row of a given column in Pandas? (I am particularly interested in the first row, but would be interested in a more general practice as well).

For example, let's say I want to pull the 1.2 value in `Btime` as a variable.

Whats the right way to do this?

```py
>>> df_test
    ATime   X   Y   Z   Btime  C   D   E
0    1.2  2  15   2    1.2  12  25  12
1    1.4  3  12   1    1.3  13  22  11
2    1.5  1  10   6    1.4  11  20  16
3    1.6  2   9  10    1.7  12  29  12
4    1.9  1   1   9    1.9  11  21  19
5    2.0  0   0   0    2.0   8  10  11
6    2.4  0   0   0    2.4  10  12  15
```

Answer (score 818, accepted):

To select the `ith` row, [use `iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix):

```
In [31]: df_test.iloc[0]
Out[31]: 
ATime     1.2
X         2.0
Y        15.0
Z         2.0
Btime     1.2
C        12.0
D        25.0
E        12.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

To select the ith value in the `Btime` column you could use:

```
In [30]: df_test['Btime'].iloc[0]
Out[30]: 1.2
```

---

### There is a difference between `df_test['Btime'].iloc[0]` (recommended) and `df_test.iloc[0]['Btime']`:

DataFrames store data in column-based blocks (where each block has a single
dtype). If you select by column first, a *view* can be returned (which is
quicker than returning a copy) and the original dtype is preserved. In contrast,
if you select by row first, and if the DataFrame has columns of different
dtypes, then Pandas *copies* the data into a new Series of object dtype. So
selecting columns is a bit faster than selecting rows. Thus, although
`df_test.iloc[0]['Btime']` works, `df_test['Btime'].iloc[0]` is a little bit
more efficient.

There is a big difference between the two when it comes to assignment.
`df_test['Btime'].iloc[0] = x` affects `df_test`, but `df_test.iloc[0]['Btime']`
may not. See below for an explanation of why.  Because a subtle difference in
the order of indexing makes a big difference in behavior, it is better to use single indexing assignment:

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Btime')] = x
```

---

### `df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Btime')] = x` (recommended):

The **[recommended way](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)** to assign new values to a
DataFrame is to [avoid chained indexing](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/), and instead use the method [shown by
andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32103253/190597),

```
df.loc[df.index[n], 'Btime'] = x
```

or

```
df.iloc[n, df.columns.get_loc('Btime')] = x
```

The latter method is a bit faster, because `df.loc` has to convert the row and column labels to
positional indices, so there is a little less conversion necessary if you use
`df.iloc` instead.

---

### `df['Btime'].iloc[0] = x` works, but is not recommended:

Although this works, it is taking advantage of the way DataFrames are *currently* implemented. There is no guarantee that Pandas has to work this way in the future. In particular, it is taking advantage of the fact that (currently) `df['Btime']` always returns a
view (not a copy) so `df['Btime'].iloc[n] = x` can be used to *assign* a new value
at the nth location of the `Btime` column of `df`.

Since Pandas makes no explicit guarantees about when indexers return a view versus a copy, assignments that use chained indexing generally always raise a `SettingWithCopyWarning` even though in this case the assignment succeeds in modifying `df`:

```
In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':list('ABC')}, index=[0,2,1])
In [24]: df['bar'] = 100
In [25]: df['bar'].iloc[0] = 99
/home/unutbu/data/binky/bin/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
  foo  bar
0   A   99  <-- assignment succeeded
2   B  100
1   C  100
```

---

### `df.iloc[0]['Btime'] = x` does not work:

In contrast, assignment with `df.iloc[0]['bar'] = 123` does not work because `df.iloc[0]` is returning a copy:

```
In [66]: df.iloc[0]['bar'] = 123
/home/unutbu/data/binky/bin/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

In [67]: df
Out[67]: 
  foo  bar
0   A   99  <-- assignment failed
2   B  100
1   C  100
```

---

**Warning**: I had previously suggested `df_test.ix[i, 'Btime']`. But this is not guaranteed to give you the `ith` value since `ix` tries to index by *label* before trying to index by *position*. So if the DataFrame has an integer index which is not in sorted order starting at 0, then using `ix[i]` will return the row *labeled* `i` rather than the `ith` row. For example,

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':list('ABC')}, index=[0,2,1])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
  foo
0   A
2   B
1   C

In [4]: df.ix[1, 'foo']
Out[4]: 'C'
```

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: DataFrames store data in column-based blocks (where each block has a single dtype).If you select by column first, a view can be returned (which is a quicker than returning a copy) and the original dtype is preserved. In contrast, if you select by row first, and if the DataFrame has columns of different dtypes, then Pandas *copies* the data into a new Series of object dtype. So selecting columns is a bit faster than selecting rows. Thus, although `df_test.iloc[0]['Btime']` works, `df_test.iloc['Btime'][0]` is a little bit more efficient.

Answer (score 45):

Another way to do this:

```
first_value = df['Btime'].values[0]
```

This way seems to be faster than using `.iloc`:

```
In [1]: %timeit -n 1000 df['Btime'].values[20]
5.82 µs ± 142 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit -n 1000 df['Btime'].iloc[20]
29.2 µs ± 1.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 37):

Note that the answer from @unutbu will be correct until you want to set the value to something new, then it will not work if your dataframe is a view.

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':list('ABC')}, index=[0,2,1])
In [5]: df['bar'] = 100
In [6]: df['bar'].iloc[0] = 99
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.16.0_19_g8d2818e-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexing.py:118: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

Another approach that will consistently work with both setting and getting is:

```
In [7]: df.loc[df.index[0], 'foo']
Out[7]: 'A'
In [8]: df.loc[df.index[0], 'bar'] = 99
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
  foo  bar
0   A   99
2   B  100
1   C  100
```

Answer (score 14):

1. `df.iloc[0].head(1)` - First data set only from entire first row.
2. `df.iloc[0]` - Entire First row in column.

Answer (score 12):

In a general way, if you want to pick up the first **N rows** from the **J column** from `pandas dataframe` the best way to do this is:

```
data = dataframe[0:N][:,J]
```

Comment: @anis: For this purpose, you would have been better writing a new question asking for the more general solution and answering it on your own, I believe.

Comment: Getting a `"unhashable type: 'slice'"`. Works ok if I do `data = dataframe[0:1][:]`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 12):

To access a single value you can use the method [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html#pandas.Series.iat) that is [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022658/8973620) than [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html#pandas.Series.iloc):

```
df['Btime'].iat[0]
```

You can also use the method [`take`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.take.html):

```
df['Btime'].take(0)
```

Comment: take should be accessed in square bracket like : df['Btime'].take[0]

Comment: @ManishChauhan No. `take` is a method that you need to call using parentheses.

Answer (score 11):

`.iat` and `.at` are the methods for getting and setting single values and are much faster than `.iloc` and `.loc`. Mykola Zotko pointed this out in their answer, but they did not use `.iat` to its full extent.

When we can use `.iat` or `.at`, we should only have to index into the dataframe once.

This is not great:

```
df['Btime'].iat[0]
```

It is not ideal because the 'Btime' column was first selected as a series, then `.iat` was used to index into that series.

These two options are the best:

1. Using zero-indexed positions:

   ```py
   df.iat[0, 4]  # get the value in the zeroth row, and 4th column
   ```
2. Using Labels:

   ```py
    df.at[0, 'Btime']  # get the value where the index label is 0 and the column name is "Btime".
   ```

Both methods return the value of 1.2.

Answer (score 7):

To get e.g the value from column 'test' and row 1 it works like

```
df[['test']].values[0][0]
```

as only `df[['test']].values[0]` gives back a array

Answer (score 2):

Another way of getting the first row and preserving the index:

```py
x = df.first('d') # Returns the first day. '3d' gives first three days.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-basics-get-value), `at` is the fastest way to access a scalar value such as the use case in the OP (already suggested by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68122940/19123103) on this page).

Building upon Alex's answer, because dataframes don't necessarily have a range index it might be more complete to index `df.index` (since dataframe indexes are built on numpy arrays, you can index them like an array) or call `get_loc()` on columns to get the integer location of a column.

```py
df.at[df.index[0], 'Btime']
df.iat[0, df.columns.get_loc('Btime')]
```

One common problem is that if you used a boolean mask to get a single value, but ended up with a value with an index (actually a Series); e.g.:

```
0    1.2
Name: Btime, dtype: float64
```

you can use `squeeze()` to get the scalar value, i.e.

```py
df.loc[df['Btime']<1.3, 'Btime'].squeeze()
```