# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning: I'm thoroughly confused

Tags: python, pandas, chaining

I'm getting the infamous pandas SettingWithCopyWarning when I run the following code segment:

```
for i in range(1, N):
    if df['deltaPressure'][i] < CLUSTER_THRESHOLD:
        df['Cluster'][i] = df['Cluster'][i-1]
    else:
        df['Cluster'][i] = df['Cluster'][i-1] + 1
```

I have tried fixing it by adding a .copy() as follows:

```
for i in range(1, N):
    if df['deltaPressure'][i] < CLUSTER_THRESHOLD:
        df['Cluster'][i] = df['Cluster'][i-1].copy()
    else:
        df['Cluster'][i] = df['Cluster'][i-1].copy() + 1
```

Unfortunately, I get no change to the warning. Lots of googling and searching StackOverflow has got me nowhere closer to understanding the fundamental error in my syntax or how I am inadvertently chaining. The code seems to run correctly, but I hate to ignore error messages in the hope that they will prove irrelevant.

I'd be very appreciative, both for a fix to my code, and for a simple explanation of why the .copy() does me no good.

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` at the same time:

- `df['Cluster']` : `__getitem__`
- `_[i] =` `__setitem__`

As explained in https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1-intro, *"pandas can't guarantee whether that first **getitem** returns a view or a copy of the underlying data. The changes will be made to the thing I called _ above, the result of the **getitem** in 1. But we don't know that _ shares the same memory as our original"* `df`.

You should use `loc`/`iloc` instead.

EDIT: Re reading your question, I add another possibility for achieving what you are doing without a for loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
N = 100
CLUSTER_THRESHOLD = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({"deltaPressure": np.random.randint(1,100, N),
                   "Cluster": np.random.randint(1,5,N)})
df["top"] = df["deltaPressure"]<CLUSTER_THRESHOLD
df["Cluster"] = np.where(df["top"], df["Cluster"].shift(), df["Cluster"].shift() + 1)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually I did, with no impact - my code now reads:   df['Cluster'].iloc[i] = df['Cluster'].iloc[i-1].copy()    and      df['Cluster'].iloc[i] = df['Cluster'].iloc[i-1].copy() + 1. Unfortunately, I still get the warning! Hence the confusion.

Comment: Have you tried using iloc including for the column selection `df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc("Cluster")] = df.iloc[i-1, df.columns.get_loc("Cluster")] +1 `?

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed work - though I must say that it is not intuitive at all, even after staring at it for a while. It really does seem to be related to the way in which Pandas is implemented. Armed with your suggestion and Google, I found a comprehensive answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254016/pandas-get-first-row-value-of-a-given-column)

Thanks a mill.