# What is the correct way to get the first row of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

The data in `test.csv` likes this:

```
device_id,upload_time,latitude,longitude,mileage,other_vals,speed,upload_time_add_8hour,upload_time_year_month,car_id,car_type,car_num,marketer_name
1101,2020-09-30 16:03:41+00:00,46.7242,131.140233,0,,0,2020/10/1 0:03:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-09-30 16:08:41+00:00,46.7242,131.140233,0,,0,2020/10/1 0:08:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-09-30 16:13:41+00:00,46.7242,131.140233,0,,0,2020/10/1 0:13:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-09-30 16:18:41+00:00,46.7242,131.140233,0,,0,2020/10/1 0:18:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-02 08:19:41+00:00,46.7236,131.1396,0.1,,0,2020/10/2 16:19:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-02 08:24:41+00:00,46.7236,131.1396,0.1,,0,2020/10/2 16:24:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-02 08:29:41+00:00,46.7236,131.1396,0.1,,0,2020/10/2 16:29:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-02 08:34:41+00:00,46.7236,131.1396,0.1,,0,2020/10/2 16:34:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-02 08:39:41+00:00,46.7236,131.1396,0.1,,0,2020/10/2 16:39:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-02 08:44:41+00:00,46.7236,131.1396,0.1,,0,2020/10/2 16:44:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-02 08:49:41+00:00,46.7236,131.1396,0.1,,0,2020/10/2 16:49:41,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-06 11:11:10+00:00,46.7245,131.14015,0.1,,2.1,2020/10/6 19:11:10,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-06 11:16:10+00:00,46.7245,131.14015,0.1,,2.2,2020/10/6 19:16:10,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-06 11:21:10+00:00,46.7245,131.14015,0.1,,3.84,2020/10/6 19:21:10,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-06 16:46:10+00:00,46.7245,131.14015,0,,0,2020/10/7 0:46:10,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-07 04:44:27+00:00,46.724366,131.1402,1,,0,2020/10/7 12:44:27,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-07 04:49:27+00:00,46.724366,131.1402,1,,0,2020/10/7 12:49:27,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-07 04:54:27+00:00,46.724366,131.1402,1,,0,2020/10/7 12:54:27,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-07 04:59:27+00:00,46.724366,131.1402,1,,0,2020/10/7 12:59,202010,18,1,,
1101,2020-10-07 05:04:27+00:00,46.724366,131.1402,1,,0,2020/10/7 13:04:27,202010,18,1,,
```

I use this code to get the data with the speed is 0 in the dataframe, and then group the dataframe according to latitude, longitude,year,month and day.

After grouping, get the first `upload_time_add_8hour` and the last `upload_time_add_8hour` of each group. If the difference more than 5 minutes between the first `upload_time_add_8hour` and the last `upload_time_add_8hour`, get the first row of data for each group, and finally save these data to csv.

I think my code is not concise enough.

I use `df_first_row  = sub_df.iloc[0:1,:]` to get the first row in the dataframe, I use `upload_time_add_8hour_first = sub_df['upload_time_add_8hour'].iloc[0]` and `upload_time_add_8hour_last = sub_df['upload_time_add_8hour'].iloc[-1]` to get the first element and the last element of a specific column.

Is there any more suitable way?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

device_csv_name = r'E:/test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(device_csv_name, parse_dates=[7], encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
df['upload_time_year_month_day'] = df['upload_time_add_8hour'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
df['upload_time_year_month_day'] = df['upload_time_year_month_day'].astype(str)
df_speed0 = df[df['speed'].astype(float) == 0.0] #Get data with speed is 0.0
gb = df_speed0.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude', 'upload_time_year_month_day'])
sub_dataframe_list = []
for i in gb.indices:
    sub_df = pd.DataFrame(gb.get_group(i))
    sub_df = sub_df.sort_values(by=['upload_time_add_8hour'])
    count_row = sub_df.shape[0] #get row count
    if count_row>1: #each group must have more then 1 row
        upload_time_add_8hour_first = sub_df['upload_time_add_8hour'].iloc[0]  # get first upload_time_add_8hour
        upload_time_add_8hour_last = sub_df['upload_time_add_8hour'].iloc[-1]  # get last upload_time_add_8hour
        minutes_diff = (upload_time_add_8hour_last - upload_time_add_8hour_first).total_seconds() / 60.0
        if minutes_diff >= 5: # if minutes_diff>5,append the first row of dataframe to sub_dataframe_list
            df_first_row  = sub_df.iloc[0:1,:]
            sub_dataframe_list.append(df_first_row)

if sub_dataframe_list:
    result = pd.concat(sub_dataframe_list,ignore_index=True)
    result = result.sort_values(by=['upload_time'])
    result.to_csv(r'E:/for_test.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True,encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first and last **element** of the column, your option is already the most efficient/correct way. If you're interested in this topic, I can recommend you to read this other Stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25254087/8294752

To get the first row, I personally prefer to use DataFrame.head(1), therefore for your code something like this:

`df_first_row  = sub_df.head(1)`

I didn't look into how the head() method is defined in Pandas and its performance implications, but in my opinion it improves readability and reduces some potential confusion with indexes.

In other examples you might also find `sub_df.iloc[0]`, but this option will return a `pandas.Series` which has as indexes the DataFrame column names.
`sub_df.head(1)` will return a 1-row DataFrame instead, which is the same result as `sub_df.iloc[0:1,:]`

Answer (score 0):

Your way out is either `groupby().agg` or `df. agg`

If you need it it as per device you can

```
#sub_df.groupby('device_id')['upload_time_add_8hour'].agg(['first','last'])


sub_df.groupby('device_id')['upload_time_add_8hour'].agg([('upload_time_add_8hour_first','first'),('upload_time_add_8hour_last ','last')]).reset_index()


device_id upload_time_add_8hour_first    upload_time_add_8hour_last 
0       1101              10/1/2020 0:03             10/7/2020 13:04
```

If you do not want it as per device, maybe try

```
sub_df['upload_time_add_8hour'].agg({'upload_time_add_8hour_first': lambda x: x.head(1),'upload_time_add_8hour_last': lambda x: x.tail(1)})

upload_time_add_8hour_first  0      10/1/2020 0:03
upload_time_add_8hour_last   19    10/7/2020 13:04
```