# How to correct this code to not raise a SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

I'm following along with this: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/01/cleaner-data-analysis-pandas-pipes.html

About halfway down the author creates a function to remove outliers:

```
def to_category(df):
    cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
    for col in cols:
        ratio = len(df[col].value_counts()) / len(df)
        if ratio < 0.05:
            df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
    return df
```

This raised a warning from Python:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "D:/I7_Education/pandas_pipe_function1/pipes3.py", line 51
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is (though I'm working my way through it, and some posts online to try to understand). I'm still trying to make sense of the documentation explanation.

I'm aware that I can suppress the warnings from Python (The code runs fine if you suppress the warnings). I would like to know how to change the code in the article so it doesn't raise a warning in the first place.

I tried contacting the author, but haven't heard back.

What I want is no suppression to be necessary. But I don't understand what the problem is well enough to figure out how to change the code to not trip a SettingWithCopyWarning in the first place.

I was not expecting the warning.  The documentation, as well as a few posts online, say to change df using loc, but I'm not changing values, or elements, in the dataframe, I'm changing the dtype of columns from object to category; `astype('catagory')` is how to do that, and I would assume that looping through columns to do it should be fine.  A friend told me to create a copy of the df that's passed to the function, and then manipulate that, then return the copy, which I also don't fully understand, but it doesn't solve the problem - it still raises the same warning.

The dataframe I'm passing to the function is a copy.  The article is only manipulating the dataset (directmarketing.csv); it reads the csv into a pandas dataframe and manipulates it directly.  I had instead created two dataframes: the first is `dataset = pd.read_csv(".\directmarketing.csv")` and the second is `marketing = dataset.copy()` and I'm only manipulating the marketing dataframe.  That way I can go back and check against the dataset dataframe and make sure things have changed the way they're supposed to, etc.

But when I call the function, I'm calling `to_category(marketing)` - I haven't touched the dataset dataframe at all.

There is a thread on stackoverflow - [Returning a copy versus a view warning when using Python pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66336670/returning-a-copy-versus-a-view-warning-when-using-python-pandas-dataframe?rq=2) - that talks about this, but it's saying to *make* a copy to *avoid* the warning, and so I'm very confused.

Is there a way to correct the code in the article so it does not trip this warning?

I'm using Python 3.10, and Idle - I'm not using an IDE with this.

Comment: Why aren't you using `loc` which as per the documentation is the correct way of indexing dataframes?

Comment: Can you explain `len(df[col].value_counts()) / len(df)` ? Are you sure need divide number of unique values per columns per length? Same like  `(~df[col].duplicated()).mean()` ?

Comment: I...don't understand your question?  Wouldn't that defeat the point of the function, and then the article?  

I thought ```loc``` required knowing the name of the columns or its position?

Sorry - I don't know how to respond to specific comments.  I'm sure there's a way, I just don't use stackoverflow enough ot know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is rewrite solution by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) with columns names in `final` list convert to dictionary by `dict.fromkeys`:

```
def to_category(df):
    final = []
    cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
    for col in cols:
        ratio = len(df[col].value_counts()) / len(df)
        if ratio < 0.05:
            final.append(col)
    return df.astype(dict.fromkeys(final, 'category'))
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you!
...
Now I have to figure out why this works.  I understand everything up to the return statement.  It makes a list of column names.  

dict.fromkeys is making a dictionary where the keys are the column names, and the value for each is 'category'.  And then astype is changing those specific column dtypes to the associated value.  Is that right?

I didn't know you could pass a dictionary to astype - I thought it had to be string.  Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @TransitoryGouda - exactly you are right, `dict.fromkeys(final, 'category')` create dictionary with same keys `category` and values by list `final` - So `return df.astype(dict.fromkeys(final, 'category'))` convert to cataegorical columns only specifid in dictionary, anothr columns are not touched.